# Eclipse PDT - Unable to begin PHP Debugging - Stuck at 78%

Tags: php, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I can not seem to get the PHP Debugger Tool in Eclipse to launch a debugging session.

Settings I have used to configure debugging are below.

Additionally I have changed my ports for xdebug to 19000 and for zend debugger to 30000

php.ini

```
; XDEBUG Extension

zend_extension=c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll

[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=19000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
```

**1) Clicked on Run -> Debug Configurations -> Server Tab**
[image: Run Configurations Server Setting]

**2) Clicked on Run -> Debug Configurations -> Debugger Setting**
[image: Run Configurations Debugger Setting]

**3) Clicked on Window -> Preferences -> Clicked on PHP Filter To Expand on Left of Window -> Installed Debuggers -> XDebug**

[image: Window Preferences PHP Filter XDebugger Setting]

**4) Clicked on Window -> Preferences -> Clicked on PHP Filter To Expand on Left of Window -> Installed Debuggers -> XDebug**

[image: Run Configurations XDebug DBGp Debugger Setting]

**5) Clicked on Run -> Debug Configurations -> Server Debugger Drop Down -> Zend Debugger Settings**

[image: Zend Debugger Settings]

Comment: Did you change xdebug remote port in eclipse xdebug settings? Are you trying to debug local server? Make sure your web launch configuration have xdebug selected.

Comment: @zulus, first of all, thank you for your assistance! I have updated my post with screenshots of the steps I took.   In order to answer the second question, I will need to ask where can I go to find if i have local server debugging started?  Thank you.  Please let me know what other information I can provide.  I have taken all necessary screenshots and can upload.

Comment: It's simple, are you connecting into server by localhost or 127.0.0.1? If yes you are on local server. On windows make sure that eclipse isn't blocked by firewall. Did you read these tutorias? https://wiki.eclipse.org/Debugging_using_XDebug and https://www.eclipse.org/pdt/documents/XDebugGuideForPDT2.0.pdf

Comment: BTW: We are working now to simplify the xdebug configuration :P

Comment: OK, so I have not succeeded on this yet.   My settings are for a local server.  I have been tempted to resort to a simple text editor but for the application I am writing I need something a bit more powerful.

Comment: Have you xdebug on phpinfo page?  Maybe this dll isn't compatible with your php distribution. To make sure this is not a problem with localhost, you can temporary set xdebug configuration to accept all debug sessions (xdebug.remote_connect_back=On).

Comment: There is no xdebug on my phpinfo page.

Comment: So xdebug isn't installed. Can you use this page to determine valid xdebug binary? http://xdebug.org/wizard.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you both zulus and axxis for your comments!

Here is the steps to achieve the resolution.

1) Go to http://xdebug.org/wizard.php

2) Construct the following  phpinfo in your webserver script and run it directly in a browser.

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

3) Highlight the entire page or press (ctrl + a) the contents of the html page (**not the page html source code**) into the page referenced in step 1.

4) Final screen shot shows the file to download (pointed to by big arrow) and the path (enclosed by rectangle).

[image: phpinfo]

[image: xdebug phpinfo dump]

[image: xdebug phpinfo result]

*The problem was solved by placing the downloaded **php_xdebug-2.3.2-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll** file into 1) and not 2).*

**1) C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext**

**2) C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\zend_ext**

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and the problem was that I had moved my Firefox installation folder.
Check what browser you have set in Window->Preferences->General->Web Browser.
If you are using an external browser, click on it, then click on Edit and check if the path to the browser is correct.

Comment: Hello axxis, thank you for your comment, I appreciate it.  I have checked the browser as you suggested and I changed to Firefox (my favorite but default browser)  as my default browser.  It turns out that my xdebug was not installed and not in the correct directory as zulus suggested.   I moved the xdebug .dll file into the correct directory C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext and then restarted wamp.  I can debug now.

Answer (score 1):

For me,

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=< hostname >
xdebug.remote_port=< port >
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
zend_extension_ts=< xdebug library location >
```

this worked, inserted in specific virtual-site php.ini, not /etc/php.ini.
Helper how-to: [this](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/documents/XDebugGuideForPDT2.0.pdf)

```
< hostname > the ip of the machine running the IDE
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, adding the *[xdebug]* configurations suggested by others to a php.ini file kept in following path C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\bin helped. Essentially it's a symbolic link that points/links to **phpForApache.ini** file under your respective php version folder that gets installed with wamp64 e.g. php5.6.25.

In nutshell, adding following lines to ***phpForApache.ini*** to helped me -

```
zend_extension = c:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.1-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
```

Hope this helps